# Nginx: How do I forward an HTTP request to another port?

Tags: nginx

What I want to do is: When someone visits `http://localhost/route/abc` the server responds exactly the same as `http://localhost:9000/abc`

Now I configure my Nginx server like this:

```
location /route {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

The HTTP request is dispatched to port `9000` correctly, but the path it receives is `http://localhost:9000/route/abc` not `http://localhost:9000/abc`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know if "/route/*" was moved to "/*" or if the intention was to re-write "/route/(.*)" from the very beginning? Because for me the answer would change to a 301 redirect or a URL rewrite.

Answer (score 135):

I hate the subtlety here, but try adding a / at the end of 9000 like below. It will no longer append "route" to the forwarded request now.

```
location /route {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simply adding `/` is well documented as the way to remove the prefix listed in the location.

Comment: it should be `location /route/`

Comment: More details for newcomers: The location directive goes under the server directive, and the server directive goes under the http directive. To reload nginx, run "nginx -s reload". Here's an example server directive: https://www.redswitches.com/blog/nginx-location/#Exploring-the-Syntax-of-NGINX-Location-Directive

Answer (score 58):

I believe you can use rewrite to remove the extra part of the URL. In your case I think you could use:

```
location /route/ {
    rewrite ^/route/?(.*)$ /$1 break;    
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

However if your app has internal links in it, they may still point to /abc/foo , and if you do this they instead need to point to /route/abc/foo so that the raw request comes in correctly. You may be better off leaving the nginx config as it is and instead configuring your app to be aware it lives at a subdirectory, if you can.

I know this is an old question, but it was the top google hit for me when I was trying to solve the same issue!

Comment: Thanks ! in this link we can review the list of variables: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#Variables

Comment: this is a better answer than others 

Answer (score 28):

Try the following

```
location /route/ {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me, as it preserves the host name.

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 13):

vim `nginx.conf`

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://compute-1-36:8787;
      proxy_redirect http://compute-1-36:8787/ $scheme://$host:8080/;
    }
  }
}
```

This code listens on 8080 and redirects to port 8787 on compute-1-36.
You can select other path in location `/`