# Hostname to Localhost with Port - OSX

Tags: mac-osx, node.js, hosts, ipfw

I am trying to run multiple `Node.js` web servers locally on my machine.

Because the code I'm writing needs to reference a domain name I'd like to keep a convention of `dev.myHost.com` and point that to the non-port-80 service running from Node (technically I'm running one on `Harp.j`s and one on `Sails.js`).

- So `dev.hostOne.com` should point to `localhost:123`
- and `dev.hostTwo.com` should point to `localhost:456`

Is this possible? If so, how.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From my understanding, it seems that you only use one local dev machine, means not connected to any network that provides a DNS.

If i am right, i would suggest to setup things like described below :

**step 1 :** Assign at least two IP address to your MAC OS (one per domain), let's say :

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
```

To setup the second IP you will have to add a second Ethernet Adapter (logical not physical).

**Step 2 :** As you don't have a DNS server, you could setup your `/etc/hosts` file, by adding :

```
192.168.0.10     dev.hostone.com
192.168.0.11     dev.hosttwo.com
```

**Step 3 :** Assign aliases to your loopback interface :

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 192.168.0.10 alias
sudo ifconfig lo0 192.168.0.11 alias
```

**Step 4 :** Setup `ipfw` to forward packets :

```
sudo ipfw add fwd 127.0.0.1,123 tcp from me to 192.168.0.10 dst-port 80
sudo ipfw add fwd 127.0.0.1,456 tcp from me to 192.168.0.11 dst-port 80
```

You are done !

Now :

- http://dev.hostone.com redirects to `localhost:123`
- http://dev.hosttwo.com redirects to `localhost:456`

[image]
[image]

---

I've setup two `Node.js` web servers to test your case :

```
$ netstat -anp tcp | grep -E "123|456"
tcp4    0    0  127.0.0.1:123    *.*    LISTEN
tcp4    0    0  127.0.0.1:456    *.*    LISTEN
```

---

**Important :** note that `ipfw` rules and loopback interface aliases are not persistent and will no longer exist after a reboot. So consider adding a startup script.

Comment: Worked BEAUTIFULLY. This is EXACTLY what I wanted.

Comment: Glad it works ! i was pretty sure that it was not totally a "duplicate" ;)

Comment: on Mac os sierra getting sudo: ipfw: command not found

Comment: @ClintM: `ipfw` has been replaced by `pfctl`.  For an example of how to open a port: https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/

Comment: It would be really nice to update the answer in the pfctl expected format.

Comment: If ipfw is not available. You have do this https://gist.github.com/allexradu/52f88344f207960621d5f086fcaf4b69

Comment: Instead of all those steps, you can assign different domains to localhost (127.0.0.1) in `/etc/hosts`, then install a web server (e.g. Nginx) and configure port forwarding in it:
https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-an-http-request-to-another-port

Comment: If you want to use Caddy and Docker to achieve this without using `ipfw` or `pfctl`, you can follow instructions in https://github.com/bibstha/local-ssl-proxy. This setups a reverse proxy with SSL support.