# Golang - Nginx proxy pass issue

Tags: nginx, go

I have a golang application running on port 3001.
`curl http://127.0.0.1:3001` gives the correct HTML response. But I am facing issues when I am trying to do a proxy_pass via NginX.

Below is my NginX configuration. I am doing a route based location block -

```
upstream my-app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

 server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        underscores_in_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        client_max_body_size 300M;

            location ^~ /theapp {               
                proxy_redirect   off;
                proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass       http://my-app;
            }
 }
```

When I access `http://example.com/theapp/`, it downloads the `my-app` binary instead of forwarding the http request to my-app.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Output of `nginx -T` -

```
nginx: the configuration file /mnt/vol1/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /mnt/vol1/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /mnt/vol1/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  12;

access_log  /mnt/vol2/logs/nginx/access.log  main-2 buffer=5k;
error_log   /mnt/vol2/logs/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  4000;
     multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    log_format  main-2 '$host $http_client_ip $remote_addr - $remote_user - $request_time [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$http_cache_control" '
                      '"$http_via" ';


    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    send_timeout 10;
    sendfile        on;
      
    upstream my-app {
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    server {
            listen       80 default_server;
            server_name  localhost;
            underscores_in_headers on;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            error_page 404 /404.html;
            client_max_body_size 300M;

                location ^~ /theapp {               
                    proxy_redirect   off;
                    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                    proxy_pass       http://my-app;
                }
    }


} 

# configuration file /mnt/vol1/nginx/conf/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}
```

Comment: Did you do something silly like put the binary inside the document root? I don't even _see_ a `root` here. Where did you define it?!

Comment: Why would we need the `root` defined if we are using the block only to proxy pass the request to another port/service?

Comment: You aren't using the block only to proxy pass. You're only passing some URLs, not all of them.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I don't want to process other requests at all.

Comment: What about your custom 404 page? That won't go to the app.

Comment: Thanks. Will handle it a bit later. Right now, I want to focus more on the issue (which is, why aren't the proxy passes working) rather than trying to address the missing parts.

Comment: Please add the log

Comment: I was focused on the issue, so here it is again: What is your document root? Where did you put this Go binary?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Go binary is in `/mnt/vol1/www/go-apps/my-app`. This binary starts a http server on 3001 port. I service is running, I can see in process list (`curl` proves it as well). There is no document root at all, for this server block.

Comment: @030 - I have log paths defined as such: 
`access_log  /mnt/vol2/logs/nginx/access.log  main-2 buffer=5k;`
`error_log   /mnt/vol2/logs/nginx/error.log;`

For these requests, I don't see either access or error logs. I have a PHP application running on a different port, I see logs for them.

Comment: That means that the document root is inherited from the level above, not that there is not one. There is always a document root, even if you don't define one anywhere, the compiled-in default will be used. But based on your new information I think the problem is that your requests are going to a different `server` block. Please edit your question to include the output from `nginx -T`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Did that. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure that is complete? It looks like things are missing. You mentioned having a PHP app on a different port, but nothing in this configuration references that app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110954/discussion-between-arunkolhapur-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: @MichaelHampton
Thing is, We have a stage machine and a production machine. In the production machine we have configs for other services as well, which unfortunately I cannot share here.

What I have shared is for the stage box. The issue is the same in both the machines.

Also, the requests are landing to the same server block. I put `return 200 'my-app server block';` and commented the proxy part. I see this response in the browser.

Comment: It's probably best to not mention things that are not on the stage box. It will only be confusing. Anyway: Did you compile a custom copy of nginx? Please post the output from `nginx -V`.

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding `/` at the end of `http://my-app`.

Not really sure how that works. But it did work.

Thanks to -
[Nginx: How do I forward a http request to another port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-a-http-request-to-another-port)